# How to pass sql query in resolvers of Apollo GraphQl Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I try to connect GraphQl and MySql and don't want to use tricky library like sequelize...
Code of my resolver:

```
  const Query = {
  users: () => {
    connection.query('SELECT id, login FROM `users`', (error, results) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      return results;
    });
  },
};
```

Response 'undefined'.  Everything is OK with connection and Apollo build response if I don't use request to DB. 
I understand that connection is async function and I have to deep somewhere there but I lost this battle...(

Please explain how to fetch data from DB using only mysql library?

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the `connection.query` with a promise, see [Asynchronous resolvers](https://graphql.org/learn/execution/#asynchronous-resolvers)

E.g.

```js
function query(sql) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(sql, (error, results) => {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      return resolve(results);
    });
  })
}

// ...
const findUsersSQL = 'SELECT id, login FROM `users`'
const Query = {
  users: () => query(findUsersSQL)
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately via promise it response 'undefined'...  Even if without sql:     const query = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const arr = [
      { id: '1', login: 'Nick' },
      { id: '2', login: 'Lena' },
    ];
    return resolve(arr);
  });
};

Comment: I found my mistake. Thank you!